# How to remove UILocalNotifications without canceling them?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am working on an app, there is a functionality of `UILocalNotification`. So, I want to enable and disable all `UILocalNotification` from a switch in the app without canceling them. The user only changes all notification settings from device and I just want to handle from my apps.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a boolean global value (or value in user defaults) and wrap all of your code which do UILocal Notification in if statement, for example:

```
if (showNotification) // <- this is your bool variable
{
    // Your code to handle notification
}
```

And in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions if you want to unregister your notification add:

```
if (!showNotification)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
else
{
    //register notification
}
```

Add desired button to your app and toogle declared value via this button.
Also if you toogle button to disable notification you have to cancel all notification and register it back when user enable it.

Hope this help.

Comment: Problem is that if he has already registered notification, there is no way to cancel them with your proposal. They will be shown even that user disabled them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you cannot do that. You will have to cancel all local notification when he disables them and ignore all future notification.

Also when he turns notifications back on just recreate all local notifications again.

Otherwise if you have notification already registered and user disables them - they will be shown anyways - there is no other way to disable them than cancelling all.

If you cannot easily re-register them for some reason of your application logic, only solution will be to keep internal list of those events and manage it on top of UILocalNotifications in case you need to recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't register for UILocalNotifications. You simply schedule them and then they fire at a certain date. If you want to stop firing them, simply surround the code where you fire them with a condition. Like so:

```
if(userHasRegisteredForNotifications)
    //Schedule a notification here
```

Unless you call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]` they will still be presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

As Grzegorz said you can't do it, all other suggestions are fine if your local notification arrive while the app is in foreground. 
You can create a table of notifications internal to the app with the enalble/disable thing and create the behavior that you want. But if you schedule one and the app is closed it will be fired anyway, independently from the notification information.
One solution could be to delete all the notification when the app goes to background and reschedule only the those that are matching the enable property. That means that you need to serialize the notification objects and/or options somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`-[UIApplication scheduledLocalNotifications]` is a `readwrite` property.

If you want to disable notifications, just save the array and set the property to `nil`.
If you want to enable notifications, set the array to the previous value.

Then comes the problem how to save the notifications...

However, in practice the simplest solution is to always cancel all notifications when disabling and create them from scratch when enabling.